Captain on his motorcycle got a speed-ticket
This one will be tough.
I'm looking for a U.S. movie.

I don't remember when it came out. But cell-phones and automatic speed camera where not really a thing at this time (see below). So roughly 1995-2002.
The hero is played by a slightly-gray aired guy, I think he was 45-55 at this time. The actor always play the good guy, he has a friendly face (from my opinion).
The hero is/was the captain of something, probably a submarine, I believe he is nemo or his ship is the nautilus but I don't find anything on google by looking for it.
I only remember the opening scene, our hero drive is slightly futuristic motorcycle and get caught by a speed camera. In the seconds he got a call on his helmet phone and a female officer (young black women with blue shirt in a call center) tells him he got a ticket.
The hero probably has a daughter and she has a boyfriend and at the end the hero sacrifice himself for the boyfriend (It's look like Armageddon too much to be correct...).


Probably was Roy Scheider in "Seaquest DSV". I will search for the episode where I see this scene.

Finally found it.
It was in the 1994 first episode of the second season of seaQuest DSV named Daggers.
The hero was Captain Nathan Bridger played by Roy Scheider who was 62 at this time.
Captain Nathan Bridger had a son but no daughter.
In France, first speed camera was installed almost ten year after that (source). And cell-phone were not really popular.
Here a retranscription :

(New Cape Quest, Florida)
(A helmeted person on a motorcycle is speeding down the road. His tags get scanned because he is going 164.6 MPH.)
(Police Station) Woman: Attention vehicle number 32189, travelling 64 miles above accepted speed allowances.
(As she speaks the motorcycle slows down.)
  Woman: Infraction Level 7. $913 dollars has been deducted from your social security account.
(The driver of the motorcycle hits the handle bar in irritation.)
Woman: Thank you.
(The motorcycle continues on and pulls up to where the new seaQuest is
  docked. The person takes off the helmet and we see that it's Captain
  Bridger. He looks at the new boat with pride.)


Congratulations, this answer is the winner of the monthly answer challenge.
